# Android Studio - Failed to resolve library in gradle

Tags: java, android

I have tried to import multiple libary for project in android studio.But it always shows error like

[image]

For this, I tried multiple solution like sdk update , studio update , build.gradle update and so on.Eventhough, i could not get any result.anyone give solution please.

Herewith I mentioned my gradle sepcification too.

app - build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abof.android"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':libraries:facebookV2')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3-beta1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:gson-2.2.4')
    compile project(':libraries:citruslibrary')

}
```

project - build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: The libraries mentioned are nowhere to be found in your build.gradle. Did you post the correct file?

Comment: It seems that the error is not in this project, maybe  in the others.

Comment: hi,The libraries were pointing to plugins related to citrus library